# NLog event logging inside Application and Services Logs

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, logging, nlog, event-log

In my project (ASP.NET C# class library project) , we are using NLog.dll (v 4.0.0.0) to log exceptions in Event Viewer in the below manner:-

```
private readonly NLog.Logger _logger;
_logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
_logger.Error(someText, someArgs);
```

Please find the NLog configurations used as below :

```
target xsi:type="EventLog"
name="eventlog"
layout="${message}"
machineName="."
source="NLogLogger"
log="Application"
```

It works fine and logs messages in the Application Log inside "Windows Logs".
However, we require the logging to be performed in a separately designated log (custom log, specific for my application under "Application and Services Logs").

We specified the name of the designated log in the config like below:-

```
target xsi:type="EventLog"
name="eventlog"
layout="${message}"
machineName="."
source="NLogLogger"
log=“MyOwnLog”
```

But it still logs messages in the same Application log.

Please let me know how I can get it logged in the designated log using NLog.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.  It's probably the source parameter.
In PowerShell you have to create the Eventlog like this:

```
new-eventlog -Source NLogLogger -LogName MyOwnLog
```

After this you can use your config.

Comment: Please format you answer so it can be more readable. Surround the command with ` .